# Spree 3.0 adding to permitted attributes in extension

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, strong-parameters

So I'm making a spree extension in which I have my own attribute that I added to `Spree::Shipment` and added an input during the checkout process, the problem is my attribute is not part of the permitted attributes for shipments, and it is not clear how to add it to the permitted attributes. I found the conversation on [this pull req](https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/3566) which says to use

```
Spree::PermittedAttributes.shipment_attributes << :my_custom_attribute
```

However, it is unclear *where do I put this!?*

"Oh, put it in `spree.rb`"

This doesn't help. I have tried putting this code in

```
lib/spree.rb
lib/spree/permitted_attributes.rb
lib/spree_decorator.rb
lib/spree/permitted_attributes_decorator.rb
```

([as suggested here](http://www.rubycoloredglasses.com/2014/04/strong-parameters-with-spree-extensions/)) and all of these result in either an error complaining about `shipment_attributes` not being defined (so presumably the code is run before the main file defining `PermittedAttributes` is evaluated) or simply nothing happens. Where should I put this code to add my attribute to the list of permitted attributes?

---

Edit: Since this seems unclear to people, I have tried all of the things listed in the links I have posted. Telling me to try the things in them is quite infuriating. Stop doing that.

Comment: "I think it might be better to add it in ApplicationController or some other file that gets reloaded with the app though. You might experience issues where rails would reload the app code and attributes would be missing on that class accessor" - Cited from the github thread... did you tried in ApplicationController?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in an initializer, as was suggested in the update of the article you posted? (http://www.rubycoloredglasses.com/2014/04/strong-parameters-with-spree-extensions/)

Comment: I also have a couple of custom attributes and I added `Spree::PermittedAttributes.shipment_attributes << :my_custom_attribute` in config/initializers/spree.rb (at the end) and it worked for me

Comment: Did you find any alternative approach? Because, putting it in spree.rb is probably not the best approach.

Comment: @anoop No, although I may have fsck'd up my installation so try the solutions I linked, they may work for you even though they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

"spree.rb" actually means `config/initializers/spree.rb`.  This is the proper place for spree config.  I noticed you/that article mentioned various files, but never this file.

Once in this file either:

```
Spree::PermittedAttributes.shipment_attributes << :my_custom_attribute
```

as you mentioned or

```
Spree::PermittedAttributes.shipment_attributes.push :my_custom_attribute
```

If that doesn't work you will need to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/3566#issuecomment-36420097) you could put it just into `ApplicationController`.

Or you could override the whole permitted_params,adding yours to whitelisted (by either putting this code straight into `application_controller.rb` after last `end`, which will 100% work, or by creating a new file(for example under lib, as you have already tried)):

```
module Spree
  module PermittedAttributes

    # bunch of code

    @@checkout_attributes = %i(
      email
      use_billing
      shipping_method_id
      coupon_code
      my_custom_attribute
    )

    # bunch of code

  end
end
```

Comment: See my edit about telling me to try things in the links I posted.

Comment: I did not mean to irritate or provoke you. I do not imagine a case though, in which my solution with app_controller would not affect the situation. But, as you say so